# Python Wrappers for CurveLab? when i try to import pyct module in my python I got this "AttributeError: module 'pyct' has no attribute 'fdct2' "

Tags: windows

python setup.py build install
running build
running build_py
copying src\fdct2_wrapper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pyct
running build_ext
building '_fdct2_wrapper' extension
swigging src\fdct2_wrapper.i to src\fdct2_wrapper_wrap.cpp
C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\swigwin-4.0.2\swigwin-4.0.2\swig.exe -python -c++ -o src\fdct2_wrapper_wrap.cpp src\fdct2_wrapper.i
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

When i try to import pyct in command prompt it shows
but when i help(pyct.fdct2) it will show AttributeError: module 'pyct' has no attribute 'fdct2'